# How does one reverse direction on a VOR radial?

Tags: navigation, pilot-technique, vor, radio-navigation

Tracking inbound, say on R-270, how do I track outbound on the same R-270? What intercept heading shall I fly?

Comment: Well, make a 180 degree turn, plus however much more seems appropriate to get back onto the radial. The bigger the intercept angle, the sooner you'll rejoin the radial, but also the greater the chance of overshooting through it. Farther from the station, the 180 will take you fewer radials off the 270R, but the same cross track distance. An intercept of 10 to 30 degrees would generally work fine.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a [procedure turn](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26656/62)?

Comment: Very much related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53981/how-do-i-determine-which-radial-intercept-angle-to-use

Answer (score 4):

Spin the obs 180 so it changes from "To" to "from" then make a 210-220 degree turn(180 plus a 30-40deg intercept) and fly until the VOR radial comes in, then track the VOR.